# ASUS Eee PC 1215B: Washed Out Display with AMD Catalyst drivers

Tags: display, asus, ati, catalyst

I have been having this problem for a while, however lately I have been trying to find ways to make my netbook perform better, visually and functionally.

When I use default Radeon graphic drivers, my colour profile seems to match that of the one on my Windows install, however when I install the Catalyst drivers, I get a washed out display that looks like the brightness is too high and the contrast too low.

I have playing around with the settings in the Catalyst Control Centre however I could not manage to get the right display.

I am using Catalyst 11.12 and my graphics card is an AMD Radeon HD 6310.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These settings work fine for me:

- Brightness -10
- Contrast 70
- Saturation 120
- Hue -30
- Temperature 6300

Comment: I don't know if this works because my charger has stopped working for my Eee PC, but I will confirm this as the answer because it is the only answer that gives details.